# filter item with checked checkbox and Multiple filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I just want to make a filter with checkbox array using jquery and javascript. Our filter does not work in group mode. filter does not work if we for multiple filters. Could you please help me to find my mistake. I want to filter through the array. The name of our array is FlyList.I want to click on a few checkboxes. Multiple filtering for us.

[image]

```js
let FlyList = [{
    id: "1",
    Airline_number: "961",
    Type_ticket: "systemi",
    Airline: "dubai",
    fly_time: "04:00-08:00",
    Class_type: "Economical"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    Airline_number: "962",
    Type_ticket: "charteri",
    Airline: "frans",
    fly_time: "08:00-11:00",
    Class_type: "Commercial"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    Airline_number: "963",
    Type_ticket: "systemi",
    Airline: "Emirates",
    fly_time: "11:00-14:00",
    Class_type: "Commercial"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    Airline_number: "964",
    Type_ticket: "systemi",
    Airline: "Emirates",
    fly_time: "14:00-17:00",
    Class_type: "Economical"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    Airline_number: "965",
    Type_ticket: "charteri",
    Airline: "dubai",
    fly_time: "17:00-21:00",
    Class_type: "Commercial"
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    Airline_number: "966",
    Type_ticket: "charteri",
    Airline: "frans",
    fly_time: "21:00-24:00",
    Class_type: "Economical"
  }
];

function customFilter(list, field, value) {

  let fill = list.filter(item => {
    if (typeof(filter) === 'Object') {
      value.foreach(val => {
        if (item[field] === value) {
          return item[field] === value
        }
      });
    }
    return item[field] === value
  });
  console.log(fill);
}

let filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.customCheck');
filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let filterTypeElement = findFilterTypeElement(e.target);
  if (filterTypeElement) {
    let field = filterTypeElement.getAttribute('data-field');
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log(field, val);
    customFilter(FlyList, field, val);
  }
}));

function getParents(el, parentSelector /* optional */ ) {

  // If no parentSelector defined will bubble up all the way to *document*
  if (parentSelector === undefined) {
    parentSelector = document;
  }

  var parents = [];
  var p = el.parentNode;

  while (p && (p !== parentSelector || p.parentNode)) {
    var o = p;
    parents.push(o);
    p = o.parentNode;
  }
  parents.push(parentSelector); // Push that parentSelector you wanted to stop at
  return parents;
}

function findFilterTypeElement(element, className) {
  let result = null;
  let parents = getParents(el);

  parents.forEach((item) => {
    if (hasClass(item, 'filter_type') && result == null) {
      result == null;
    }
  });
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="filters">
  <div class="collapse show" id="collapseFilters">
    <div class="filter_type" data-field="Type_ticket">
      <h6>
        Type of ticket
        <div class="switcher float-left ">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="selectall" />
            all Type of ticket
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck w-100 " id="filter-check">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="systemi" class="individual" />
            systemi
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck w-100" id="filter-check2">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name=""
              value="charteri"
              class="individual"
            />
            charteri
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_type airlineSelection" data-field="Airline">
      <h6>
        airline
        <div class="switcher float-left">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
            all airline
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck" id="">
            <input type="checkbox" value="frans" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            frans
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptions" /> dubai
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="emirates" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            emirates
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="frans" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            frans
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="emirates" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            emirates
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="dubai" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            dubai
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="filter_type" data-field="Class_type">
      <h6>
        Class_type
        <div class="switcher float-left">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
            all Class_type
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck" id="">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="economical"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            economical
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="commercial"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            commercial
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_type" data-field="fly_time">
      <h6>
        fly_time
        <div class="switcher float-left">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
            all fly_time
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck" id="">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="04:00-08:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            04:00-08:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="08:00-11:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            08:00-11:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="11:00-14:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            11:00-14:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="14:00-17:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            14:00-17:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="17:00-21:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            17:00-21:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="21:00-24:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            21:00-24:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inside the `customFilter`, what is `if(typeof(filter) === 'Object')` for? what is `filter` here?

Comment: list.filter means FlyList.filter

Comment: What does the line `if(typeof(filter) === 'Object')` do? There is no `filter` variable anywhere.

Comment: Also, **1)** `hasClass` function is missing from the snippet. **2)** Inside `findFilterTypeElement` the code should be `let parents = getParents(element);`

Comment: To select multiple filters at the same time. We have to make some changes here.
let filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll ('. customCheck');
filterCheckboxes.forEach (checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener ('change', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault ();
  let filterTypeElement = findFilterTypeElement (e.target);
  if (filterTypeElement) {
    let field = filterTypeElement.getAttribute ('data-field');
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log (field, hour);
    customFilter (FlyList, field, hour);
  }
}));

Comment: There are many ways to solve a problem. We have used this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array.forEach is not appropriate here.  Once a filter section is enabled and fails, the item is excluded and you need to break out of the loop.

Here is an outline of an approach

```
function isEnabled(filterGroup){
  // todo check DOM for checked
}

function passes(filterGroup, item){
  return filterGroup.items.every(filterItem=>{
     // todo return true if item passes filterItem
  }
}

let itemsFiltered = itemsAll.filter(item=> {
   let pass=true
    for(let filterGroup of filterGroups) {
      if(isEnabled(filterGroup) && !passes(filterGroup, item)) {
          pass=false;
          break;
      }
    }
   return pass;
})
```

Comment: Delete the (let fill) code. And will I put your code instead?

Comment: When I click on the checkbox. The array associated with the checkbox is filtered for me. But I want . Using a few checkboxes returns an array (returns a box using multiple filters). This means returning an array using multiple filters.

Comment: The filter.passes function would return true only if all checkboxes in the group matched the item.

Comment: thank you. This part of my code works. I want to do this by changing the section (filterCheckboxes.forEach).

Comment: Please, if you can help, correct this code by changing this section.